# Return data from Doctrine inside a JsonResponse object

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My problem is that I want to return some data that I get from Doctrine inside a `JsonResponse` object. I get the data with a `QueryBuilder`, like this:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->createQueryBuilder('u');
$data = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

$JSONResponse = new JsonResponse();
$JSONResponse->setData($data);
```

However, the data inside the `JsonResponse` looks empty:

```
data: {
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    .....
}
```

Does anyone know how I can return the data this way correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're getting the array of `User`s correctly from the DB using Doctrine (you can check that with a simple `var_dump($data)` after you fetch them.

However, when your put you array of `User`s into the `JsonResponse`, those objects will be serialized, and since (I guess) the properties in the `User` class are `private`, the serialization of each one is just an empty array `[]`...

You need to pass a plain array of data to `JsonResponse` instead of an array of `User`s, for which you have a few options:

1. Use [`$qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#title.1.7.1) to get directly a plain array instead of an array of `User` objects.
2. Make `User` class implement [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface, so you define how the objects should be serialized.
3. (**Recommended**) Generate a plain array from your `User` objects using some specialized serialization library like [JMS Serializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) (or manually if you prefer), and then put that data into the `JsonResponse`.

Comment: Thank, I tried to use the method " getArrayResult()" but as it is a composite object (users have other objects inside) it only returns things from the user object, not from the others.

Comment: I also tried the serializable interface and it works perfectly. But as they are composite objects, I have to implement the interface to all objects. But now I know why I was going through the whole "not returning anything" in the JSON response. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at a serialization library like JMS Serializer https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

Comment: I am using JMSSerializier in my project. I tried that but when I do $this->serializer->serialize($qb->getQuery()->getResult(), 'json');  The answer is not good, it adds a "/" to my JSON and representation is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Hy, in this case use getArrayResult instead of getResult if you can

Comment: Thank, but I tried to use the method " getArrayResult()" but as it is a composite object (users have other objects inside) it only returns things from the user object, not from the others.